# Calculate expected value of stochastic variable within integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, expected-value

Given that $X(t)$ has expected value $m$, how do I caluclate the expected value of 
$$\int_0^1X(t)dt$$
?

Comment: My first answer would be something like : $E[\int_0^1X(t)dt]$ (If this exists of course) ;-

Comment: @TheBridge Yes but how do I evaluate it?

Comment: Apply Fubini theorem (..if everything is nice of course).

Comment: You also need to know the law of $X(t)$ for  every  $t$